# How to diagram structure of database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a huge database and I want to diagram it with all the relations and indexes.Is there any way to diagram it automatically ( I want to chart of all the relations used in the database.

PS :I am using oracle database.

Comment: In order for any tool to diagram your database automatically you usually need foreign keys defined. Is this the case? Toad also has a diagramming tool.

Comment: Can you please provide me a link to download this software ?

Comment: Its not free but it's been used at every Oracle shop I've been to. Here's a link: http://software.dell.com/products/toad-for-oracle/ Seriously though you might be more effective if you worked out how to look this kind of thing up yourself!

Answer (score 3):

Oracle Data Modeler should have you covered. It supports reverse engineering ERDs as well.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html

Comment: and it's included with your database, no cost

Answer (score 2):

you can go for rational rose uml design software. Export your db and import into it to produce design .Try it once.

http://getintopc.com/softwares/development/rational-rose-enterprise-edition-free-download/